# Moment js return always zero time

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs, date-difference

I am trying to get duration between now and future time:

```
var d = moment.utc('27.03.2018 - 15:43:01', 'DD.MM.YYYY - HH:mm:ss')
var v = moment.utc(moment.duration(d).asMilliseconds()).format("HH:mm:ss")
console.log(v);
```

Problem is that v is always 00:00:00, why?

d is valid moment object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calling `duration(param)`, the parameter must be one of the values described in the docs: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/creating/

ex: if you call it like `moment.duration(100)`, this creates a duration of 100 milliseconds. A duration represents a span of elapsed time, or an "amount of time".

If you pass a date object to it (`moment.duration(d)`), this doesn't make sense. You're trying to create a duration (a span of elapsed time) from a date value. And that's a misunderstanding of 2 concepts:

- a date/time represents a specific point in the calendar
- a duration represents a span of elapsed time, and it's not attached to any specific point in the calendar

You can do things like:

- calculate the difference between 2 dates: the result is a duration (between today 10 AM and tomorrow 2 PM, the difference - the duration is 28 hours - not considering DST effects: https://www.timeanddate.com/time/dst/transition.html)
- add/subtract a duration to a date: today 8 AM, plus a duration of 2 hours, equals today 10 AM

But creating a duration from a date, without having another date as reference, doesn't make sense. In this specific case, moment just decided to return a duration with the value equals to zero: print the value of `moment.duration(d)`, you'll see `P0T` - that's the ISO 8601 representation of a zero-duration: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations

Then you call `.asMilliseconds()`, that returns the total amount of milliseconds that the duration represents. In this case, it's returning zero.

Then you call `moment.utc()` passing the result above as parameter. In other words, you're doing the same as `moment.utc(0)`. When you pass a number to `utc()`, it interprets this number as "the number of milliseconds since Unix epoch": https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/

As you're passing zero, the result is the Unix epoch itself, which is January 1st 1970 **at midnight** in UTC.

Then you call `.format("HH:mm:ss")` to print the hours, minutes and seconds. As `moment.utc(0)` is at midnight, the result is `00:00:00`.

If you want to calculate the difference between 2 dates, use the `diff` method as explained by Pavlo's answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
var d = moment.utc('27.03.2018 - 15:43:01', 'DD.MM.YYYY - HH:mm:ss');
var v = d.diff(moment.utc(), 'milliseconds');

console.log(v);
```

You want to use `diff` because it calculates the difference between two `date` objects. The second parameter is what unit of time you want returned.